# How to fix 'Tweet' object has no attribute 'retweetCount'

Tags: python-3.x

Using snscrape for this example.
With python 3.8 and snscrape 0.3.4

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter

keyword = '(COVID19)'

tdf = None

for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(keyword + ' since:2021-08-01 lang:pt').get_items()) :

    if i >50:
        break
    print(tweet.date.date())
    print(tweet.retweetCount)    
    print(tweet.renderedContent)
```

I get this:

```
AttributeError: 'Tweet' object has no attribute 'retweetCount'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with `snscrape`'s version (`0.3.4`). After installing the development version (that is, `0.3.5.dev138+ga6b6f3f` now) your code works.

To install the development version, use the command below (copy-paste from [here](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape)):

```
$ pip3 install git+https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape.git
...
$ pip3 list | grep snscrape
snscrape                          0.3.5.dev138+ga6b6f3f
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Tweet.retweetCount` in snscrape 0.3.4 — https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/blob/v0.3.4/snscrape/modules/twitter.py

Update to the mainline, or similar appropriate version, which adds many more `Tweet` properties including `retweetCount` — https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/blob/master/snscrape/modules/twitter.py

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

**The Error is with the version of snscrape you are using**

Try using -

```
!pip install snscrape==0.4.3.20220106
            OR
!pip3 install snscrape==0.4.3.20220106
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31051672)

Comment: @SLART This does answer the question IMO. It uses Google Colab syntax from what I can see, but that's fixable.